# How to vertex slide outwards?

Tags: geometry

How can I extrapolate a vertex/line along its tangent, as in the gif below?

[image: gif of extending vertex along tangent]

Comment: do you mean to slide your vertex along the side outwards? There is a double G shortcut to activate sliding of the vertice on the edge, once you Alt whíle GG is active you will see that your vertice can slide outwards... is that what you wanted?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i wanted, thank you. can you add that as the solution?

Comment: Hopefully it will help even more people, I notice a lot that many people don't know about this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressing G twice will activate sliding of the vertex on the edge:
[image]

If you hold Alt while GG is active, you will see that yellow line is extended and you can slide outwards:

**Edit:** You can also press C instead of holding Alt to activate sliding outwards

[image]

Comment: Alternatively you can press C to toggle the line extension on or off. More friendly towards users with disabilities.

Comment: true, somehow I only use C with knife... don't know why